# Color table cell, error

Tags: tables, colortbl

Here's the problem, in TeXShop or TeXnicle, the following code complies without fuss:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}
\hline
Correct & Incorrect\\
$\begin{aligned}
3(2x-5)^2&=3(4x^2-20x+25)\\
&=12x^2-60x+75
\end{aligned}$
 &
$\begin{aligned}
3(2x-5)^2&=(6x-15)^2\\
&=36x^2-180x+225
\end{aligned}$
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If, I instead, invoke `colortbl` - and I don't even call it:
No dice!

Errors galore:

```
Typesetting file:/Users/linovari/Documents/12MM[2017]/Unit 4 - Statistics/discrete
Typesetting with /Users/linovari/Library/Application Support/TeXnicle/engines/pdflatex.engine
[0/3] Typesetting file:/Users/linovari/Documents/12MM[2017]/Unit 4 - Statistics/discrete
****************************
*** Typsetting: discrete
*** Output dir: /Users/linovari/Documents/12MM[2017]/Unit 4 - Statistics
*** Output dir: .
***  N typeset: 3
***  Do bibtex: 1 (bibtex)
****************************

***------------------------------------------------------------
*** Run 1 of 3...
***------------------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./discrete.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/Users/linovari/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/array.sty
Style-Option: `array' v2.0d  <90/08/20> (F.M.)
English documentation dated  <90/08/20> (F.M.)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
))
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)
)
(./discrete.aux
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\stretch {.5}\kern \z@ \d@llarbegin 
                                                  \insert@column \d@llarend ...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend 
                                                  \hskip \stretch {.5}\or \d...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\stretch {.5}\kern \z@ \d@llarbegin 
                                                  \insert@column \d@llarend ...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend 
                                                  \hskip \stretch {.5}\or \d...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\stretch {.5}\kern \z@ \d@llarbegin 
                                                  \insert@column \d@llarend ...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend 
                                                  \hskip \stretch {.5}\or \d...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\stretch {.5}\kern \z@ \d@llarbegin 
                                                  \insert@column \d@llarend ...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

./discrete.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend 
                                                  \hskip \stretch {.5}\or \d...
l.7 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}
]
(./discrete.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2016/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2016/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb
>
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on ./discrete.pdf (1 page, 35654 bytes).
SyncTeX written on ./discrete.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on ./discrete.log.
***------------------------------------------------------------
*** Running bibtex on discrete ...
***------------------------------------------------------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: discrete.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file discrete.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file discrete.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file discrete.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Compile aborted.
*** pdflatex.engine has completed.
```

Any suggestions?

I've updated the packages TeXShop calls. Sorry, I'm not experienced enough to understand the errors. I've imported tons of examples that purportedly work, but for me they don't. `colortbl` seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your console output contains:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/Users/linovari/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/array.sty
Style-Option: `array' v2.0d  <90/08/20> (F.M.)
English documentation dated  <90/08/20> (F.M.)
```

That means, `colortbl` is from TeX Live 2016, but `array.sty` is found in a different place (`/Users/linovari/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/array.sty`) and the date if from ancient history: 1990-08-20.

Solution: Rename `/Users/linovari/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/array.sty` or move it out of the way, that it is not found by TeX anymore.
Then, TeX can find the `array.sty` from TL 2016 to make `colortbl` happy.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks a million, or should that be a billion! I'm in the process of updating MacTex, although I think that mentioned file is a relic. Sorry don't know enough to know what to delete and what to keep. Any suggestions would be welcome.